# Loading a list of Keywords is very slow in SDL Web 8 CME

Tags: web8, database, keyword

We are using SDL Web 8.1 and we are facing a issue while accessing Keywords inside a Category which takes more then 2 min but before upgrading to Web 8 from 2013 SP1 HR1 it was quite fast.

The Category consist more then 2000 Keywords. We are running the CMS database maintance script regularly (executing first `AnalyzeStats.sql` and then `rebuildindexes.sql` script). What could be the reason to load the Keywords very slow?

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: I am assuming, you are facing issue while accessing keywords inside your web application. Can you share the code snippet which you are using to access the keywords.

Comment: @MukeshKumar i m facing this issue in SDL Web8 Content Manager Explorer not inside the custom web application.

Comment: Oracle or MSSQL? Do you have DB reports revealing badly optimized queries?

Comment: We are using Oracle and maintenance task is running regularly

Comment: @MukeshKumar the performance issue reported is regarding SDL Web CME itself and not any external web application. We recently upgraded from 2013 SP1 to Web 8.1 and also added an extra CMS box for load balancing and high availability. Since the upgrade the CME feels slower than compared to 2013 SP1 single CM instance.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. Please contact SDL Customer Support for a hotfix.

Comment: @SudhakarRao can please share us the hotfix detail

Answer (score 2):

We recently had same issue in our one of the environment. but after long analysis we discovered its due to Database. We are using SQL Azure and it was mistakenly configured to **Basic Tier**. Basic Tier could not handle so much category keyword queries etc so it was taking 2-3 minutes for loading set of keywords.

WE upgraded the azure to high performing tier and performance improved significantly to 5-10 seconds from minutes.

Comment: RajKumar thanks for your answer but in our scenario we are not using Windows Azure.We are using oracle database and it is in our network only.

Comment: what are your oracle server configurations?